# MPMoviePlayerController dismiss on input

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to create a sort of a screen saver video for my main application, where if a user is inactive for sometime in the app, I trigger the screen saver video.

To this end, I'm playing a full screen video (locally on disk) using `MPMoviePlayerController`. This is a looping (repeating) video and no on screen controls (`MPMovieControlStyleNone`).

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
    if (moviePath)
    {
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    }

    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    _moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This works well as expected.

But I need to fix the following issues

- Cancel video playback on input (cancel on input)
- When I double tap on video, it zooms in. This needs to stop.

Any constructive feedback is highly appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to add a tap gesture recognizer to the `MPMoviePlayerController` view, which should solve both of your problems:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(handleTap:)];

[_moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
```

Then the method to handle taps:

```
 - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

        //Move your moviePlayBackDidFinish: code to a new method
        //that this method and moviePlayBackDidFinish: will call
 }
```

Comment: Hi ChrisH, Thanks for the reply. I guess I could have done what you suggested. But I wanted to add fade in/out to the screen saver as well (I didn't mention that on the question. My bad). So I opted to the below answer (which I posted in case if it would be helpful to someone else). Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in a case where it might be helpful to someone else.

I'm posting below what I ended up doing in the end. I ended up not going with `[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];` since I wanted a fade in / fade out animation of the screen saver as well (I didn't mention that on the question above).

Sorry for the long script. But all one would want to do is to hook up a button action to `- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender`

```
@interface ScreenSaverVC ()
typedef enum
{
    FADE_IN,
    FADE_OUT,
}FadeType;

@end

@implementation ScreenSaverVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initScreenSaver];
}

#pragma mark - Interface builder
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [self startScreenSaver];
}

#pragma marl - MPMoviePlayerController notifications
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];

    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Holition plugin methods
- (void) startScreenSaver
{
    [_moviePlayer play];
    [self startFade:FADE_IN withCompletion:^{

    }];
}

- (void) stopScreenSaver
{
    [self startFade:FADE_OUT withCompletion:^{
        [self moviePlayBackDidFinish:[[NSNotification alloc]
                                      initWithName:@"MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification"
                                      object:_moviePlayer userInfo:nil]];

    }];
}

- (void) initScreenSaver
{
    NSURL *url;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"ScreenSaver" ofType:@"m4v"];
    if (moviePath)
    {
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    }

    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    _moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [_moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
}

#pragma mark - Util methods
- (void) startFade :(FadeType)type withCompletion:(void (^) (void))compHandler{

    float startAlpha = 0.0f, endAlpha = 0.0f;

    switch (type) {
        case FADE_IN:
            startAlpha = 0.0f;
            endAlpha = 1.0f;
            break;
        default:
            // FADE_OUT
            startAlpha = 1.0f;
            endAlpha = 0.0f;
            break;
    }

    [_moviePlayer.view setAlpha:startAlpha];

    //FadeIn or FadeOut
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

        [_moviePlayer.view setAlpha:endAlpha];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (compHandler) {
            compHandler();
        }
    }];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSInteger count = [[event allTouches] count];
    if(count > 0)
        [self stopScreenSaver];
}
@end
```